# How can I enable a text field when a button is clicked?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, field, jbutton

before I start, I'm a beginner programmer.

How can I enable a text field when a button is clicked.

I have two frames, one that has the JFields and the other for the exception.
When the exception occurs > **setEditable(false)**
but what statement should I make to enable the JFields once the user click on okay button -that i've made in the exception-?

I've tried to add static boolean to exception frame, and inside the action performed of this class I initialized that boolean to **true**.

in the other class, I added an if statment, if that boolean is true, then setEditable(true)

-========-
The point of this program, that when the exception occurs the user cannot enter anything in the fields until he closes the exception window.

I wish you'd help me.

With all love, programmers.

**The code of action performed for THE EXCEPTION WINDOW FRAME ( having Okay button. )**

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      {
      allow=true; //static boolean
        Container TheFrame = OKButton.getParent();
        do TheFrame = TheFrame.getParent(); 
                 while (!(TheFrame instanceof JFrame));

        ((JFrame) TheFrame).dispose();

     }
```

**The code of action performed for THE MAIN PROGRAM (having three fields, an exception will occur once the user enters  non digits )**
I added some comments to clarify.

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

     try{
        r =Double.parseDouble(RField.getText());
        s=Double.parseDouble(SField.getText());
        h=Double.parseDouble(HField.getText());


        Cone C = new Cone(r,s,h);//class cone 
        if (event.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
           JButton clickedButton = (JButton) event.getSource();
           if (clickedButton == VolumeButton) {
              Result.append("VOLUME =  "+C.volume()+ "\n");
              ifV= true;//this's for clearing the fields for new entries.


           }
           if (clickedButton == AreaButton) {
              Result.append("SURFACE AREA =  "+C.surfaceArea()+ "\n");
              ifA= true;//this's for clearing the fields for new entries.


           }

           if(ifA&&ifV){ // clearing the fields for new entries.
              SField.setText(CLEAR);
              HField.setText(CLEAR);
              RField.setText(CLEAR); 
              ifV=false; ifA= false;}



        } 


        SList.addShape(C);

     }

        catch(NumberFormatException e){ 

        //Object of type "Exception__" already created 

           Ex.setVisible(true);//class "Exception__" is the one i've made for Exception window

           SField.setText(CLEAR);
           HField.setText(CLEAR);
           RField.setText(CLEAR);
           SField.setEditable(false);
           HField.setEditable(false);
           RField.setEditable(false);


        }/*here, if the user clicked on -that okay in Exception window- 
and variable allow initialized to "true" those statements should extend. I guess? 
- everything worked correctly except for this ?*/
     if(Ex.allow){    
        SField.setEditable(true);
        HField.setEditable(true);
        RField.setEditable(true);  } 


  }
```

**THANK YOU ALL IT FINALLY WORKED.**

I added

```
Ex.allow(SField,HField,RField);
```

to the catch.

and added this method in class Exception__:

```
        public void allow(JTextField js,JTextField jh,JTextField jr){

     HField =jh;
     SField =js;
     RField =jr;
  }
```

finally, to the action performed of class Exception__:

```
  SField.setEditable(true);
           HField.setEditable(true);
           RField.setEditable(true);
```

WOHOOOO. It feels so awesome lol. Thanks all. should I delete my question or leave it for others who might face the same problem as mine? :P

Comment: Post what code you have and the stack trace for the exception and someone will gladly help you.

Comment: If you use a JDialog, it will automatically disable the parent window until it goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question needs a lot more detail. But if all you want to to show an 'exception window' and allow the user to do anything else only after she dismisses this window, I think all you need is a MessageDialog:
See [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)

If you need more details to be displayed you can create your own modal [`JDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html).

See [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough.
I tried the JOptionPane and it successfully works, but I was only trying the idea of disabling and enabling the field according to the exception window. 
Thank you so much for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Make the text field hiden by writing:

jTextfield.setVisible(fasle);

in the constructor of your form code. than use the button event " Action -> Action Performed " and write the code:

jTextfield.setVisible(true);

and thus your text field will be visible only after the button will be clicked.

Comment: I think setEditable is more useful in my situation. 
I'll try your advice using Editable method. Thanks a lot.